# Why is the code showing 'int' object is not subscriptable?

Tags: python, typeerror

```
x = int(input())
l =[]


for i in range(x):
  l.append(input().split(" "))

for i in range(x):
  
  k = int(l[i][1])
  sum = int(l[i][2])
  odd =[]
  for j in range(int(l[i][0])):
        
    odd.append(1+2*j)
    

  for j in range(len(odd)):
      
    s =0
    for l in range(len(odd)):
      if(odd[j]==odd[l]):
        s = s+ odd[l]*k
      else:
        s = s+ odd[l]
    if(s==sum):
      print(odd[j])
      break
```

When I run this code, it works perfectly fine for 1 iteration. But as soon as we move to next iteration, the code starts showing error:

> TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

in the line where I have declared `k = l[i][1]`. What's causing this error and how can I solve it?

Comment: `for l in range(...)` assigns an int to `l`. Loops (and all other control structures for that matter) don't introduce a new scope in Python, so that `l` is the exact same variable as the `l` you defined at the start.

Comment: Please post the full stacktrace and provide an example of the expected input for the application.

Comment: @Brian make that an answer, it's sufficient to resolve this post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line

```
for l in range(len(odd)):
```

assigns an `int` to `l`. Loops (and all other [control structures](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html) for that matter) don't introduce a new [scope](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#resolution-of-names) in Python, so that `l` is the exact same variable as the `l` you defined at the start. When `k = l[i][1]` is reached on the next iteration, you're attempting to index an `int`, hence the error.

You'll need to pick a different name for the variable in the for loop.